# Should minor edits not be rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, too-minor

Why are those types of forceful edits approved when the content is logically and syntactically sound? Below I have provided some of my posts which have been edited in this fashion. So I would like to know, should minor edits not be rejected?

**Edit:1**
[image]
**Edit:2**
[image]
**Edit:3**
[image]

Comment: Related: [Approve as too minor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149722/179833)

Comment: **"you can edit the post into better shape"** Mr. Ben point is too good.... @NSPostWhenIdle thanks!

Comment: That's all fine and well, but we're dealing with edits here which don't show up in review at all. There is nothing to reject, approve as too minor or improve.

Comment: @Bart - YES! Actually people who have less than `2k` repu they like to edit for gain `2pt` and who have more than `2k` repu they like to see his name below the answer ... Thats not good thing but people do and no body cant do anything in this.

Comment: @Bart - Thanks for asked to Mr. Emil about this.

Comment: @VakulSaini You're welcome. In any case, your posts have not been harmed in any way. (Though the code edits are borderline, if not inappropriate). If someone does end up harming your posts, you can always roll back to a previous revision. So there is no real danger here. Perhaps some annoyance from time to time.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152572/is-this-considering-appropriate-editing/

Comment: Removing those curly braces was a bad edit, since using those are just a stylistic choice. But many of your posts have unnecessary fluff(greetings, thanks, etc.) and bad formatting. Your indentation is bad, you leave out the space after punctuation marks, abuse inline code as highlighting,... So I'd edit them when running into them.

Comment: As commented below, that particular edit might have been unnecessary, I can admit that. My main reason was to remove the lines that took up space (new-lines), and while doing so, I decided to remove the brackets as well. My editing is mostly to "prettify" StackOverflow, and my goal with it is that the post owners see what changes I have made, and apply the same changes to their following posts (hence most my edits are on new users). However, I greatly appreciate critique, as I can definitely still learn! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are all users who [have the privilege to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) without the need for review, because of their reputation being over 2000. As a result there is nothing to reject.

Whether or not those edits are the best they can be is another matter altogether. (I would personally have fixed several other issues in each post you show us) In general, minor edits are okay if they fix all the problems in a post. Then they are not too minor.

Comment: But only space correction should not be fair.

Comment: I agree that it's a fairly lousy edit and in addition does not address the capitalization problems. There is however nothing to reject because these edits won't show up for review.

Comment: you can see in first edit - Mr. Emil only removed the brackets... I know for execute the single line in for loop there is no need of brackets but if i put brackets that doesn't mean it is wrong... I think this should be stop to make a wrong edit.

Comment: As I said, I agree it's a lousy edit. But there is practically nothing that can be done about it. This user has the privilege to edit without further review. If you feel it harmed your post, feel free to roll it back. But that's about it. I would not have made that edit and instead would have fixed some of the other issues which are present in that post.

Comment: and in many places the code change made would fail code reviews as having {} in is a requirement - I would roll it back

Comment: @Mark That would be fair enough indeed.

Comment: That particular edit might have been unnecessary, I can admit that. My main reason was to remove the lines that took up space (new-lines), and while doing so, I decided to remove the brackets as well. My editing is mostly to "prettify" StackOverflow, and my goal with it is that the post owners see what changes I have made, and apply the same changes to their following posts (hence most my edits are on new users). However, I greatly appreciate critique, as I can definitely still learn! :)

Comment: Plus, a rollback is totally all right, if you would like to do that. Rollbacks are also a way to learn what others mean :)

Comment: @Emil Thank you for being so constructive about this. I did not mean to call you out in any way, but thought this discussion might be instructive. I'm glad to see you take it as such.